# Delegate using (methodes)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, methods, delegates, overloading

I´m tring to get to work with Delegates, however I cant figure out how I use them correctly.
I think to know what they are for.

```
namespace Delegates_Events_Excptions
{
    public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            PlayerStats.ScoreDelegate scoreDelegate = new PlayerStats.ScoreDelegate(PlayerStats.OnGameOver(allPlayerStats));
            Console.WriteLine(scoreDelegate);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        /// <summary>
        ///  Here in this tutorial you get to know the difference between using delegates and not
        ///  You safe a lot of Time and code when u do so
        ///  You can use it when you use two or more methods that do the same with different values
        /// </summary>
        public class PlayerStats
        {
            public string name;
            public int health;
            public int dmg;
            public int gold;

            public delegate int ScoreDelegate(PlayerStats stats);

            public static void OnGameOver(PlayerStats[] allPlayerStats)
            {
                int playerNameMostHealth = GetPlayerNameTopScore(allPlayerStats, stats => stats.health) ;
                int playerNameMostGold = GetPlayerNameTopScore(allPlayerStats, stats => stats.gold);
                int playerNameMostDmg = GetPlayerNameTopScore(allPlayerStats, stats => stats.dmg);
            }

            public static int GetPlayerNameTopScore(PlayerStats[] allPlayerStats, ScoreDelegate scoreCalculator)
            {
                string name = "";
                int bestScore = 0;

                foreach (PlayerStats stats in allPlayerStats)
                {
                    int score = scoreCalculator(stats);

                    if (score > bestScore)
                    {
                        bestScore = score;
                        name = stats.name;
                    }
                }

                return bestScore;
            }
        }
}
```

I get the error:  CS7036    There isn´t any argument, that the formal parameter "allPlayerStats" from"Program.PlayerStats.OnGameOver(Program.PlayerStats[])" conforms.
I thank you already :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method `void OnGameOver(PlayerStats[] allPlayerStats)` is not compatible with delegate `int ScoreDelegate(PlayerStats stats);` as types of parameters are different.

You need to change this

```
public delegate int ScoreDelegate(PlayerStats stats);
```

to

```
public delegate int ScoreDelegate(PlayerStats[] stats);
```

This fixes error `CS7036`.

Next things you need to do:

> 1. define `allPlayerStats`
> 2. add attributes `health`, `gold` and `dmg` to class `PlayerStats`.

Comment: Thank you, I got rid of CS7036, but how could I define allPlayerStats in this case?

Comment: I cant upyote yet I dont have enough point... but I will when I have

Answer (score 0):

> I get the error: CS7036 There isn´t any argument, that the formal parameter "allPlayerStats" from"Program.PlayerStats.OnGameOver(Program.PlayerStats[])" conforms.

Yup, that's right. The line

```
PlayerStats.ScoreDelegate scoreDelegate = new PlayerStats.ScoreDelegate(PlayerStats.OnGameOver(allPlayerStats));
```

is invalid for a couple of reasons. First, there's no such variable as `allPlayerStats` in this scope; second, `PlayerStats.OnGameOver(allPlayerStats)` is not a function, so you can't make a `ScoreDelegate` out of it.

What are you trying to accomplish with this line? Since I don't know what you're trying to accomplish, I can only guess what you would need to do in order to accomplish it.

But I'm *guessing* that you want to:

- Modify the function `PlayerStats.OnGameOver` so that it returns something.
- Get rid of the variable `scoreDelegate`, because it's not serving any purpose.
- Call `Console.WriteLine` with the result value of `PlayerStats.OnGameOver`.

Comment: First of all thank you for the asnswer, but I want it to return something yes^^